# Probability of prediction of multiple choices.

Tags: probability

A person predicts daily if the price of stocks of Tesla, Ford, and GM will go up or down. If his prediction on the stock price of Tesla is correct $2$ times out of $4$, for Ford it is correct $2$ times out of $4$ and for GM it is correct $3$ times out of $7$, then what is the probability that at least two of his predictions are correct on a given day?

I've arrived at the solution as follows:

$P(Tesla)=>\frac{2}{4}$, $P(Ford)=>\frac{2}{4}$, $P(GM)=>\frac{3}{7}$

$P(Tesla \& Ford) =>\frac{2}{4}.\frac{2}{4} => \frac{1}{2}$

$P(Tesla \& GM) =>\frac{2}{4}.\frac{3}{7} => \frac{3}{14}$

$P(GM \& Ford) =>\frac{3}{7}.\frac{2}{4} => \frac{3}{14}$

I need help solving, how can I narrow down to the probability of at least two predictions correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to obtain the probability that at least two of the three stock predictions are correct, you must add the probabilities that exactly two predictions are correct and the probability that all three predictions are correct.

Let $T$, $F$, and $GM$ be, respectively, the events that the predictions are correct for Tesla, Ford, and General Motors stocks.  Then the probability that at least two predictions are correct is:
$$\Pr(T \cap F \cap GM') + \Pr(T \cap F' \cap GM) + \Pr(T' \cap F \cap GM) + \Pr(T \cap F \cap GM)$$
Assuming independence, we obtain
\begin{align*}
& \Pr(T \cap F \cap GM') + \Pr(T \cap F' \cap GM) + \Pr(T' \cap F \cap GM) + \Pr(T \cap F \cap GM)\\
& \qquad = \Pr(T)\Pr(F)\Pr(GM') + \Pr(T)\Pr(F')\Pr(GM) + \Pr(T')\Pr(F)\Pr(GM)\\
& \qquad\qquad + \Pr(T)\Pr(F)\Pr(GM)\\
& \qquad = \Pr(T)\Pr(F)[1 - \Pr(GM)] + \Pr(T)[1 - \Pr(F)]\Pr(GM)\\ 
& \qquad\qquad + [1 - \Pr(T)]\Pr(F)\Pr(GM) + \Pr(T)\Pr(F)\Pr(GM)\\
\end{align*}
I will leave the actual calculations to you.